# Simple model that explain the flow of electrons in metals

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, electrostatics

I am not quite clear about how electrons (negative electric charges in general) flow through a metal.

I imagine the metal as a lattice of small positive charges $+q$ that can not move and the - and + of the battery (source) as two strong charges $-Q$ and $+Q$. The current will be a negative charge $-e$ that is somehow initially placed close to $-Q$. Under the strong attraction of  $+Q$ and repulsion of "-Q" the $-e$ charge will start to move. However it appears it will get stuck in the network of positive charges (even if the collisions are considered elastic) finally sticking to one of them.

Am I missing something. Can this model be improved to work. Can the $-e$ charge reach $+Q$?

Note: I do not want to involve in the model the Quantum Mechanics or other concepts excepting the law of Coulomb and Newton's laws.

[image]

Comment: I want to emphasis that I do not look for answers that make use of Quantum Mechanics.

Comment: Unfortunately you can't really do that. The description of electrons in atoms and atomic lattices is a quantum mechanical one.

Comment: I think that from Earnshaw's theorem the charge should not be able to get stuck in one spot (in the limit where the ions are point charges).

Comment: @Gert What about the [Drude model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drude_model)? It reproduces Ohm's law but fails for example for the heat capacity for which you need QM.

Comment: @Praan: why go back to a pre-QM model?

Comment: @Gert Because OP asks for a Newtonian model.

Comment: There is no source of charge or anything like that. There is potential difference which results in a finite average flow of electrons. If atoms condense into a metal, the outer electrons which are weakly bound can easily escape and may wander around, scattering at the ions that are left behind. The simplest model which describes conduction in metals as electrons in a "pinball machine" is the Drude model, which is a classical model.

Comment: @Praan: there really is no point in regressing. Better to educate.

Comment: @Gert What do you mean? Regressing as in, giving a classical model? Every student starts by learning classical physics first. To understand quantum mechanics you also need to understand where the classical theories fail and in order to understand that you must first study the classical theories imho.

Comment: @Praan: many, like me, disagree with that outdated teaching method. See 'lies to the children'.

Comment: Praan, The Drude model is quite interesting for me.

Answer (score 1):

You can't really explain the conductivity in metals without basic quantum mechanics.

Metals as made up of lattices of metal atoms, packed at very close distances. The outermost and least tightly bound (to the nucleus) electrons, the valence electrons, occupy atomic orbitals  of the least energy.

Due to the close vicinity of the atoms and the similarity in energy of the valence electron orbitals, the latter show enough overlap to form a *conduction band*. This is illustrated in the figure below:

[image: Conductivity band.]

[Source, p. 142](http://files.rushim.ru/books/neorganika/housecroft.pdf)

Here the atomic orbitals $2s^1$ of the lithium atoms fuse together into a 'mega molecular orbital', called the *conduction band*. In this conduction band the electrons can move more or less freely.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the metal is totally filled with positive nuclei and negative electrons,
but the outer electrons are quite able to move about from one atom to another,
because of the way all the atoms are packed in a lattice.

That's why metals conduct heat so well.
The electrons are like a gas filling the metal, and they can easily carry momentum.
They can't get *out* of the metal of course, because the positive charges hold them back.

And if there is any sort of electric field, they can easily follow it.
Sometimes they bounce off the atoms, and that's what electrical resistance is.